# ¿Cómo puedo manejar un error en package.json?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, npm

Tengo un problema con package.json. Este es un proyecto clonado de un repositorio de github, y revisé las comas y están bien. así que no sé dónde está el error. Esto es lo que dice la terminal:

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Emege\package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Emege\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-22T03_46_29_710Z-debug.log
```

Leí este artículo, pero no me ayudó  https://dev.to/redslug/7-solutions-to-ejsonparse-or-unexpected-token-npm-install-error-20nh. Y diferentes posteos de stackoverflow
y este es el package.json

```
{
  "name": "tvpassport",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Autentificacion de usuarios",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "my world master"
  },
  "author": "Jean Mariños",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-redis": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "express-session": "^1.12.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.2.5",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "swig": "^1.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: copié y pegué tu json en mi local y no tiró ningún problema

Answer (score 0):

Una solución rápida que te propondría hacer es simplemente borrar el package.json y hacer uno nuevo.

1- cd /laDireccion/tuCarpeta
2- npm init -y
3- Instalar las dependencias

Con ello ya podrías solucionar tu error.

Answer (score 0):

A me funcionó!!! solo verifica en una IDE ( Visual Studio Code) alguna falla de sintaxis del package.json, en mi caso fue una coma adicional al final del los valores.

Lo bueno de las IDEs es que pueden detectar alguna falla de sintaxis en tu archivo JSON.

Una vez lo hallas corregido, nuevamente prueba el comando npm install y se deberá instalar correctamente todas las dependencias.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ok lo probé en mi maquina y el log de error, una linea dice esto

```
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
```

que significa que Package.json tiene en la parte de scrpits, palabras reservadas que son pretest, test posttest.
¿Cúal es el problema entonces?. probablemente que tu estas colocando como nombre a un script con la palabra reservada test

```
"script":{ "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" }
```

por lo que si le cambias el nombre "test" a otro nombre cualquiera debería funcionar.

En caso de que no sea eso. Verifica que el archivo package sea en formato json y no js, y si no por último te recomiendo que vuelvas a instalar el npmn y las dependencias que necesitas.